# show table on gridview column click

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which have some columns. I have made **name** column as a hyperlink.

I have a table named- **'tblAdd'**. On Page load event I made it invisible. I want that when I click column hyperlink, table display.

How can I do this using asp.net ?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Name" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnCheckedChanged="sellectAll"
            >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAll" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="sellectAll"  />    
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name"  
                SortExpression="Name" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="linkName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Name") %>' OnClick="displayTutorial_Click" NavigateUrl='#'>
                     </asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>   
    </asp:GridView>
```

**My Default.aspx.cs-**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Label1.Visible = false;
    GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;
    //GridView1.DataBind();
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            fillLanguageGrid();
            tblAdd.Visible = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: i dont see any `tblAdd` table !

Comment: where do you want to display this table tblAdd

Comment: @Ashok--what is the need to show that code..?

Comment: @Krunal--On same page when click hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it using Grid View row command event.

Do something like this-

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        //To get the Selected link text field on textbox
        if (e.CommandName == "displayLink")
        {   
            txtEditName.Text=((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).Text;
        }
    }
```

On default.aspx-

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" >
      <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="linkName" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("Name")%>' OnClick="linkBtn_Click" CommandName="displayLink"></asp:LinkButton>
      </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```